# How can GHC convert a polymorphic numeric literal into an arbitrary type with an instance of Num?

Tags: haskell, polymorphism, ghc, typeclass

As far as I can tell, GHC can convert any numeric literal with default polymorphic type `Num a => a` into any type with an instance of `Num`. I'd like to know whether this is true and a little about the underlying mechanism.

To explore this, I have written a datatype called `MySum` which replicates (part of) the functionality of `Sum` from Data.Monoid. The most important part is that it contains `instance Num a => Num (MySum a)`.

Note - This just so happens to be where my question go its start. The Monoid is not specifically relevant. I've included a portion of that code at the bottom of this question, just in case it is useful for an answer to refer to the contents.

It seems that GHCi will happily comply with an input of the form "v :: MySum t", under the following conditions:

1. v is a polymorphic value of type `Num a => a`
2. t is a (possibly polymorphic) type under `Num`

As far as I can tell, the only numeric literals compatible with the type `Num a => a` are ones that look like integers. Is this always the case? It seems to imply that a value can instantiated to any type under Num exactly when that value is integral. If this is correct, then I understand how something like `5 :: MySum Int` might work, given the function `fromInteger` in `Num`.

With all of that said, I can't figure out how something like this works:

```
*Main Data.Monoid> 5 :: Fractional a => MySum a
MySum {getMySum = 5.0}
```

If it's possible to explain this in a novice-friendly way, I would appreciate it.

---

The instance `Num a => Num (MySum a)`, as promised:

```
import Control.Applicative

newtype MySum a = MySum {getMySum :: a}
  deriving Show

instance Functor MySum where
  fmap f (MySum a) = MySum (f a)

instance Applicative MySum where
  pure = MySum
  (MySum f) <*> (MySum a) = MySum (f a)

instance Num a => Num (MySum a) where
  (+) = liftA2 (+)
  (-) = liftA2 (-)
  (*) = liftA2 (*)
  negate = fmap negate
  abs = fmap abs
  signum = fmap signum
  fromInteger = pure . fromInteger
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mostly have it correct: an integer literal `5` is equivalent to `fromInteger (5 :: Integer)`, and thus has type `Num a => a`; and a floating-point literal `5.0` is equivalent to `fromRational (5.0 :: Rational)` and has type `Fractional a => a`. This does indeed explain `5 :: MySum Int`. `5 :: Fractional a => MySum a` isn't that much trickier. Per the above rule, this expands to:

```
fromInteger (5 :: Integer) :: Fractional a => MySum a
```

`fromInteger` has type `Num b => Integer -> b`. So for the above expression to type check, GHC has to unify `b` with `MySum a`. So now GHC has to solve `Num (MySum a)` given `Fractional a`. `Num (MySum a)` is solved by your instance, producing the constraint `Num a`. `Num` is a superclass of `Fractional`, so any solution to `Fractional a` will also be a solution to `Num a`. So everything checks out.

You might be wondering though, if `5` gets passed through `fromInteger` here, why does the value that ends up inside `MySum` look like a `Double` in GHCi? This is because, after type checking, `Fractional a => MySum a` is still ambiguous—when GHCi goes to print that value, it needs to actually choose an `a` in order to select an appropriate `Fractional` instance, after all. If we weren't dealing with numbers, we might end up with GHC complaining about this ambiguity in `a`.

But there's a special case [in the Haskell standard](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/decls.html#default-decls) for this. The brief overview is, if you have an ambiguity issue like the above that involves only numeric type classes, Haskell in its wisdom will pick either `Integer` or `Double` for the ambiguous type and run with the first one that type checks. In this case, that's `Double`. If you'd like to know more about this feature, [this blog post](http://andrew.gibiansky.com/blog/haskell/haskell-typeclasses/#_defaulting_rules) does a decent job of motivating and elaborating on what the standard says.

Comment: Thanks - and the default type picking info was very helpful.

Answer (score 4):

As you have found out, the integer literal `5` [amounts to](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch6.html#x13-1360006.4.1):

```
fromInteger 5
```

As the type of `fromInteger` is `Num a => Integer -> a`, you can instantiate `5` to the `Num` instance of your choice, be it `Int`, `Double`, `MySum Double`, or anything else. In particular, given that `Fractional` is a subclass of `Num`, and that you wrote a `Num a => Num (MySum a)` instance, `5 :: Fractional a => MySum a` works just fine:

```
5 :: Fractional a => MySum a
fromInteger 5 :: Fractional a => MySum a
(pure . fromInteger) 5 :: Fractional a => MySum a
MySum (fromInteger 5 :: Fractional a => a)
```

> It seems to imply that a value can instantiated to any type under Num exactly when that value is integral.

Things get a little subtle here. An integral value can be *converted* to any type under `Num` (via `fromInteger` and, in the general case, [`fromIntegral`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:fromIntegral)). We can instantiate an integer literal like `5` as anything under `Num` because GHC handles the conversion for us, by desugaring it to `fromInteger 5 :: Num a => a`. However, we can't instantiate the monomorphic value `5 :: Integer` as a `Double`, nor can we instantiate `5 :: Integral a => a` to a non-`Integral` type like `Double`. In those two cases, the type annotations further restrict the type, so that we have to perform the conversion explicitly if we want a `Double`.